# Use function in closure

Tags: swift

I am trying to use a function within a closure but I am receiving an error 'cannot convert value of type () to closure result type Bool'. The following code demonstrates the error. How can I make this work?

```
func test1(){
    test2(){ success in
        self.test1()
    }
}

func test2(completionHandler: (Bool) -> Bool){
    completionHandler(true)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You specify that the `test2` closure returns a `Bool`, so return one:

```
func test1(){
    test2 { (success) -> Bool in
        test1()
        return success
    }
}
```

Have `test2`'s closure return void if you don't want to return a value from it:

```
func test1(){
    test2 { (success) in
        test1()
    }
}

func test2(completionHandler: (Bool) -> Void){
    completionHandler(true)
}
```